# How to get categorical data back after transformations?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a DataFrame:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
'foo': ['hi', 'no', 'please', 'no', 'yea', 'hi'], 
'bar': [1, 5, 7, 2, 4, 5], 
'zoo': ['car', 'bike', 'car', 'bus', 'bus', 'car']
})
```

And I created dictionaries featuring column names as keys, and the column/rows value as the value

```
X = data.iloc[:]
X_dicts = X.T.to_dict().values()
```

Which produces:

```
{'foo': 'hi', 'bar': 1, 'zoo': 'car'}
{'foo': 'no', 'bar': 5, 'zoo': 'bike'}
{'foo': 'please', 'bar': 7, 'zoo': 'car'}
{'foo': 'no', 'bar': 2, 'zoo': 'bus'}
{'foo': 'yea', 'bar': 4, 'zoo': 'bus'}
{'foo': 'hi', 'bar': 5, 'zoo': 'car'}
```

Now I want to turn each dictionary into a `numpy` array, so that I can put the arrays into a `scikit-learn` classifier, so I did this:

```
vec = feature_extraction.DictVectorizer()
X_vec = vec.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

Which produced:

```
[[ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 5.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 7.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 2.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 4.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 5.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]
```

So far so good. However, when I try to reverse the vectorizer using its `.inverse_transform` method, I don't get back what I expected (which is my original list of dictionaries). I get this:

```
[{'foo=hi': 1.0, 'bar': 1.0, 'zoo=car': 1.0}, 
 {'foo=no': 1.0, 'bar': 5.0, 'zoo=bike': 1.0}, 
 {'foo=please': 1.0, 'bar': 7.0, 'zoo=car': 1.0}, 
 {'foo=no': 1.0, 'bar': 2.0, 'zoo=bus': 1.0}, 
 {'foo=yea': 1.0, 'bar': 4.0, 'zoo=bus': 1.0}, 
 {'foo=hi': 1.0, 'bar': 5.0, 'zoo=car': 1.0}]
```

So can someone tell me how I can get back my original list of dictionaries? (These --> `X_dicts = X.T.to_dict().values()`). And can you also explain why trying to get the pre-transformation data using the `.inverse_transform` method with DictVectorizer, isn't as easy as say using the same method with PCA?

Comment: Not an answer on your question, but do you know `pd.get_dummies(data)`. This gives you the numeric array you want to use in sklearn at once. And it will probably be easier to transform such an array back to your original columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html),

> When feature values are strings, this transformer will do a binary one-hot
>     (aka one-of-K) coding: one boolean-valued feature is constructed for each of
>     the possible string values that the feature can take on. For instance, a
>     feature “f” that can take on the values “ham” and “spam” will become two
>     features in the output, one signifying “f=ham”, the other “f=spam”.

So the behavior you are seeing is exactly as expected.

To recover the original DataFrame, you could iterate through the `feature_map`
returned by `vec.inverse_transform` and reverse the one-of-K coding so
that, for example, `{'foo=bar': 1.0}` becomes `{'foo':'bar'}`:

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.feature_extraction as FE

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'foo': ['hi', 'no', 'please', 'no', 'yea', 'hi'], 
    'bar': [1, 5, 7, 2, 4, 5], 
    'zoo': ['car', 'bike', 'car', 'bus', 'bus', 'car']})

X_dicts = data.to_dict('records')
vec = FE.DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
X_vec = vec.fit_transform(X_dicts)

def inverse_transform(vec, X_vec):
    feature_map = vec.inverse_transform(X_vec)
    result = list()
    for dct in feature_map:
        newdct = dict()
        for k, v in dct.items():
            if '=' in k:
                k, v = k.split('=', 1)
            newdct[k] = v
        result.append(newdct)
    return result

data2 = pd.DataFrame(inverse_transform(vec, X_vec))
print(data2)
```

yields

```
   bar     foo   zoo
0    1      hi   car
1    5      no  bike
2    7  please   car
3    2      no   bus
4    4     yea   bus
5    5      hi   car
```